# cassandra installation failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have been trying to install datastax c* and getting stuck at the below line. It doesn't go forward after this line. May I know what the issue can be?

```
NFO  [main] 2016-02-01 11:09:01,032  CassandraDaemon.java:205 - JVM Arguments: [-Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=991, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=991, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader, -ea, -javaagent:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -Xms495M, -Xmx495M, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/dse/cassandra/hotspot_compiler, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=, -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/dse/dse.pid, -Dsearch-service=true, -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/dse/tomcat, -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/dse/tomcat, -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/dse/tomcat/conf/logging.properties, -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager, -Dtomcat.logs=/var/log/tomcat, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1454342934.hprof, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1454342934.log, -Djava.library.path=:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/native/Error:_JAVA_HOME_is_not_set./lib:/usr/share/dse/hadoop/native/Error:_JAVA_HOME_is_not_set./lib, -Dsolr.solr.home=solr/, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=991, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=991, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader]
```

Comment: Anything else in your ouput.log or system.log? Does the dse process stop?

Comment: Need much more info than the above. Please edit your question and add how you installed datastax,what was installed and how you tried to start it. Also include your OS

Answer (score 0):

I see exactly the same issue when starting DSE in a Vagrant VM (CentOS 7) that does not have enough RAM allocated - are you running in Vagrant / a VM, or on hardware with limited memory?

> If you set the ram to `2096` or higher, you should see DSE start up successfully.

DataStax is pretty resource intensive, though it's unfortunate the error messages aren't more helpful here!

(The tell-tale symptom here is `Error:_JAVA_HOME_is_not_set` in the command line)